# formatting Date in a Button

Tags: javascript, date

I need  help in modifying the date output to only be day name, month, day, year for a button output, instead of the full format. How do I shorten it?  Here is what I have:

```
<h2 id="psu1">Spooky Candles</h2>
<button onclick="getElementById('psu1').innerHTML=Date()">
  How soon can I get some delivered?
</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```html
<h2 id="psu1">Spooky Candles</h2>
<button onclick="getElementById('psu1').innerHTML=new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US')">
  How soon can I get some delivered?
</button>
```

You can find more information here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect. I see  now where I was going wrong when I tried it myself.  I was adding the .toLocaleDateString after 'Date" without the (). Thanks for your help.